# Creating non-linear neuron model from linear and actual rates

Tags: methodology, theoretical-neuroscience

In "Theoretical Neuroscience" by Dayan and Abbott, section 2.2 "Estimating Firing Rates", it describes how by using a linear model in combination with averaged experimental firing rates you can acquire a non-linear model graphically. This is shown in the figure below: [image: non-linear]

Given the synthetic neuron [defined here](https://gist.github.com/Seanny123/78676146d7745cb2527e), I was able to acquire both average experimental firing rates, as well as a linear model. I calculated the linear model by first acquiring the Spike-Triggered-Average using a white noise signal and then convolving it with the same white noise signal. Given that you can acquire the kernel according to:

[image: kernel]

And that you can the acquire a linear model given:

[image: convolution]

where $s(t-\tau)$ is the original white-noise stimulus.

However, when I try to plot this result, I get a graph that looks like:

[image: non-linear]

Given this graph, my reasoning and [my code](https://github.com/Seanny123/SYDE552/blob/28328b116d809b380653a218d7b9336eac44feea/lnp/Q2.ipynb), where could I be going wrong?